# Get merchant private data in order state change notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-checkout

I am using google checkout with a ruby on rails application. I have added merchant private data in HTML API like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="shopping-cart.merchant-private-data" value="123">
```

Merchant private data is only accessible in new order notification.

Is there any way to access it in order state change notification??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of (only in `new-order-notification`).

You'd probably want to know that [Google Checkout will be retired in November](http://googlecommerce.blogspot.com/2013/05/an-update-to-google-checkout-for.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply. It means that i have to switch from google checkout to google wallet?

Comment: @Arif there is a [Google Checkout Office Hours session](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/505515436/) scheduled on May 23, 10AM - 11AM PST that should be helpful. It's not the same API at all. [Instant Buy API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/) is the "replacement" if you are selling physical and/or digital goods. If it's just the latter (digital), then [Digital Goods API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/) is your best bet.